# Distribution of the inner product of Gaussian processes

Tags: pr.probability, stochastic-processes

Suppose that $X(s)$ and $Y(s)$ are second order real Gaussian processes (independent or not), respectively $X\sim \mathcal{N}(\mu_1,\mathcal{K}_1)$  and $Y\sim \mathcal{N}(\mu_2,\mathcal{K}_2)$, and $s\in S\subset\Bbb{R}^d$.   Assume that $X$ and $Y$ are a.s. $L^2(S)$.

Are there any standard results about the distribution of the inner product of $X$ and $Y$?  I.e. define the real random variable

$$
Z = \langle X,Y\rangle_{L^2(S)} = \int_SX(s)Y(s)ds
$$  is the distribution of $Z$ related in some nice way to the covariance operators $\mathcal{K}_j$?

Comment: The first thing I would try is to compute the expected value of $Z$. But it seems that the integrals $\int_SE[X(s)]ds$ etc. need not exist, given your conditions. What are you hoping to learn about $Z$? Can you assume that $f(s)=\mu_1(s)\mu_2(s)$ and $g(s)=E[X(s)Y(s)]$ are $L^1(S)$? If yes, the expected value of $Z$ exists and can be easily expressed in terms of the integral of $f+g$.

Comment: (use Fubini-Tonelli)